# how to change the chunk time interval?

Tags: timescaledb

how can we change the chunk time interval, when it is way too large?

use case:

- we have an existing hypertable, where we have set the `chunk_time_interval` to 1 month (when using [create_hypertable()](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#create_hypertable)).
- this was fine for the last months, but now the data-rate will be increased by a factor of 1000

e.g. I think we cannot just use [set_chunk_time_interval](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#set_chunk_time_interval), because it will not affect the current chunk: so when a new month-chunk has just started when the data-rate is increased, this chunk would get huge and only the newer chunks would be right-sized.

So what is the best way to deal with this case?

So to clarify: we want to have *one* hypertable, where the older data has a different chunk size than the newer data.

Comment: I've created a feature request [#3472](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/3472)

Answer (score 5):

We do not currently offer a method of changing the range of an existing chunk, but you can use `set_chunk_time_interval` to change the next chunk to a (say) day or hour-long period.

One approach if your database isn't too large is just to dump your data (e.g., to CSV), then recreate the database with a different setting.  Parallel copy will help with faster loading:  https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-parallel-copy

(Timescale person here)

Comment: I don't think dump/restore fits my use-case: the existing (old) data has the correct chunk size, only the new data in the table has a different chunk size: or do you mean that I should drop the newest chunk, change the chunk interval and then restore the data of the newest chunk?